# Java swing mini project in eclipse

Tags: swing

Need to do a mini project using java swing......  Our Professor has told us to concentrate on using as many features or functions we can of java swing ie the front end the GUI and concentrate less on the back end part ie the database or the files whatever we use........
I have searched the internet and did not find any project suitable.....
He has told us to do a game or something but not a project which requires to much working on back end like a railway reservation system etc which requires DB working......
Help from any books or any web site where i can get some info about projects in java swing will be appreciated........
Thanks in advance..........

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: I've done a stopwatch, a spirograph, and a roulette wheel and board as demonstration Swing projects.